# I am having this laravel 8 error Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have this button

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('generate-pdf',$data->id)}}">Export to PDF</a>
```

```
this is my route

    Route::get('generate-pdf/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\PDFController::class, 'generatePDF'])->name('generate-pdf');
```

this is my controller but when I var dump it does get the data and store it in $data variable. so my problem is why do i still get this error.

```
public function generatePDF($id)
{

$data = PersonalRecord::find($id);

var_dump($data);

$pdf = PDF::loadView('generate_pdf', $data)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
   
return $pdf->download('softcopy.pdf');
// return $pdf->stream();
}
```

and this is my pdf page (still sample not my final pdf design)

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<a href="{{route('generate-pdf')}}">Generate PDF</a>
<h1>{{$data->name}}</h1>
<div>
    <p>{{ $data->first_name }}}</p>
</div>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your button link from:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('generate-pdf',$data->id)}}">Export to PDF</a>
```

To

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('generate-pdf',['id' => $data->id])}}">Export to PDF</a>
```

Comment: still the sam error

Comment: You have mentioned two buttons i.e `Export to pdf` and `Generate PDF`. The button that calls the controller function `generatePDF` should be the one with the `id`.